# How to throw warnings for two fields simultanouesly in Thymeleaf

Tags: spring, error-handling, thymeleaf

I have this code for application in Spring + Thymeleaf:

```
<div class="form-field-input-2-in-row">
    <input type="number" step="any" class="form-control" th:field="*{originalBLG1}" th:errorclass="has-error"/> -
    <input type="number" step="any" class="form-control" th:field="*{originalBLG2}" th:errorclass="has-error"/>
    <div class="form-error" th:if="${#fields.hasErrors('originalBLG1')}">
        <ul>
            <li th:each="err : ${#fields.errors('originalBLG1')}" th:text="${err}"/>
        </ul>
    </div>
</div>
```

Is there any way to catch error for two fields at the same time, in example:

```
<div class="form-error" th:if="${#fields.hasErrors('originalBLG1', 'originalBLG2')}">
```

Comment: What you are trying to achieve can be done with a custom validator, which will allow you to validate your form as you please (taking in mind two inputs together, independently, whatever).

Comment: Can you post some example, I can't imagine how to start